# variable to use with finding the title of an element

Tags: jquery, attr

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var $postBG = $('.post .poster-profile img'); 
$postBG.find("[title='male']")
    .closest('tr')
      .addClass('male')
        .children('td')
         .removeClass('row1 row2');
$postBG.find("[title='female']")
   .closest('tr')
     .addClass('female')
      .children('td')
       .removeClass('row1 row2');
 });
```

Just trying to find if the img title is female or male, and then do the following codes above. I tried

```
$postBG.attr("male")
```

that did not work though any help please

Comment: It's impossible to say, without your HTML and/or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: if the div .post then div .poster-profile img (which would be male or female) has the title male, to the closest tr addClass to make it blue or whatever the tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` finds the elements within the context of the selected element, you can use `filter` method:

```
var $postBG = $('.post .poster-profile img'); 
$postBG.filter('[title="male"]').foo()
```

or `attribute` selector instead:

```
var $postBG = $('.post .poster-profile img[title="male"]');
```

Comment: if I tried the second one var male = $('.post .poster-profile img[title="male"]');  and var female = $('.post .poster-profile img[title="female"]');

also would this work if there are multiple images in that .poster-profile?

Comment: @user1760670 Yes, it would work for all images, can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @user1760670 Your markup is invalid, withput using table tags browser doesn't render the `tr` and `td` elements.

Comment: there are table tags. I just used google chrome to select the content I needed. Since all the data is parsed through the hosting sites php.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RWe7H/1/

that should fix that issue. Just needed to add a table tag on top

Comment: @user1760670 Okay, your image has a `title='Male'` attribute not `title='male'`. try with uppercase `Make` string.

Comment: well that would be the case :/ I didn't know that that had to be case sensitive. Thanks